# Warning: Cannot modify header information (with a twist)

Tags: php, headers, debug

```
Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output
started at /home/ezekiel/public_html/boxsponsive/wp-
content/themes/BoxSponsive-Portfolio/class.wp-less-styles.php:3) in
/home/ezekiel/public_html/boxsponsive/wp-includes/pluggable.php on line 934
```

So, I'm sure that you've all seen this error before for one reason or another. However, the problem is a bit different this time.

I've gotten rid of extra lines, made sure the file's encoding is right, basically, I've tried the usual fixes. There are no plugins on this site.

The code that seems to be causing the problem is here: http://pastebin.com/3TSDWhTS

I've used this code with no issues (on other servers) before, but I don't really know PHP... Can anyone spot the problem?

P.S. Telling me to remove lines at the top isn't working. Need other ideas...

**Update:** I feel like an idiot. There was a different file with the same bug (extra line), and that's why the error didn't go away. Rookie mistake, really.

Comment: Finally it went off huh? Congrats!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Goin with @One Trick Pony...

Change:

```
<?php /* You really don't want to touch this file if you don't know what you're doing. */     ?>

<?php

    class WP_LESS_Styles extends WP_Dependencies { ....
```

To:

```
<?php /* You really don't want to touch this file if you don't know what you're doing.*/

     class WP_LESS_Styles extends WP_Dependencies {...
```

Answer (score 0):

remove:

```
?>

<?php
```

from lines 1 - 3.

The new line character is considered output.

Comment: I did this. Same problem. Doesn't change a thing.